# Is it a valid way to optimize the stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, optimization

I have a stored procedure called `Optimized_GetArticlePost` and I want to optimize it.

Current stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Optimized_GetArticlePost]            
    (@PostID int)
    --[Optimized_GetArticlePost] 
AS                                  
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;                                  

    //declare all the required variables.. 

    -- LIST ALL ATTACHMENTS                                           
    SELECT [FileName] 
    FROM CS_PostAttachments                  
    WHERE contenttype LIKE 'audio/mpeg' 
      AND FILENAME LIKE '%.mp3' 
      AND isremote = 1 
      AND postid = @Postid ------returns a seperate table

    --GET THE FB FEED IMAGES FOR THIS  POST
    SELECT ImageURL 
    FROM PostFBImageURL 
    WHERE PostID = @PostID------returns a seperate table

    --GET STORY AT GLANCE DATA                                  
    SELECT 
        StoryImage, StoryContent, ALT 
    FROM 
        PostRelatedData 
    WHERE
        PostID = @PostID------returns a seperate table

    --GET POST REFERENCES                                  
    SELECT ReferenceData 
    FROM PostReferences  
    WHERE PostID = @PostID------returns a seperate table
END
```

From the above stored procedure, each and every `select` statement returns a table.. which I don't want and want to eliminate

Optimized stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Optimized_GetArticlePost]            
    (@PostID int)
--[Optimized_GetArticlePost] 715049
AS                                  
BEGIN 
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    ----Declare variable table...
    DECLARE @Temp TABLE (FileName nvarchar(MAX),
                         ImageURL VARCHAR(MAX),
                         StoryImage nvarchar(MAX),
                         StoryContent nvarchar(MAX),
                         ALT nvarchar(MAX),
                         ReferenceData nvarchar(MAX) )  

    SET NOCOUNT ON;                                  

    -- LIST ALL ATTACHMENTS
    INSERT INTO @Temp (FileName)
        SELECT [FileName] 
        FROM CS_PostAttachments                  
        WHERE contenttype LIKE 'audio/mpeg' 
          AND FILENAME LIKE '%.mp3' 
          AND isremote = 1 
          AND postid = @Postid

    --GET THE FB FEED IMAGES FOR THIS POST   
    INSERT INTO @Temp (ImageURL) 
        SELECT ImageURL 
        FROM PostFBImageURL 
        WHERE PostID = @PostID

    --GET STORY AT GLANCE DATA    
    INSERT INTO @Temp (StoryImage,StoryContent,ALT) 
        SELECT StoryImage, StoryContent, ALT 
        FROM PostRelatedData 
        WHERE PostID = @PostID

    --GET POST REFERENCES  
    INSERT INTO @Temp (ReferenceData) 
        SELECT ReferenceData 
        FROM PostReferences  
        WHERE PostID = @PostID

    SELECT * FROM @postDate                             
END
```

In the above optimized stored procedure, I insert the data into a table variable and select from that temp table at once at the end..

So, my question: is this the right way to optimize the stored procedure or not..OR want suggestions on how to optimize in this situation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's better to use `UNION ALL` instead of inserting into a table variable.

Comment: You have not inserted data into a temporary table, you have inserted into a table variable. A temporary table is better than a table variable at handling many rows.

Comment: This part of you WHERE clause seems incorrect: contenttype LIKE 'audio/mpeg' . Are you missing '%' before audio/mpeg ?

Comment: @Igor Will you please illustrate this in code...

Comment: @t-clausen.dk You mean to say that i should use temp table rather than using table variable...right?

Comment: @t-clausen.dk on your 2nd comment please ignore LIKE and all that....thanks

Answer (score 1):

First off : why does your temp table have **ALL** `(n)varchar(max)`?? Don't just use `(N)VARCHAR(MAX)` everywhere because you're too lazy to think about what a good, sensible length for a `(n)varchar` column would be! Know your data - use the **most appropriate** data types! If you **REALLY** must have over 8000 chars - that should be the exception, not the rule!

And also: either use `varchar` or use `nvarchar` - I would try to avoid mixing those two - either you **NEED** Unicode - then use `nvarchar` - or you don't need it - then use `varchar`.

I think this is horrible - now you get up to **4 rows** for each `@PostID` - is that really what you want??

```
FileName    ImageUrl    StoryImage    StoryContent   ALT   ReferenceData
------------------------------------------------------------------------
TheFile     NULL        NULL          NULL           NULL  NULL
NULL        SomeUrl     NULL          NULL           NULL  NULL
NULL        NULL        SomeImage     Content        ALT   NULL
NULL        NULL        NULL          NULL           NULL  ReferenceData
```

Seems like a really bad idea.

What you **most likely** want is a **JOIN** across those table - so that you get **ONE ROW** for each `@PostID`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetArticlePostWithJoins]
    (@PostID int)
AS                                  
BEGIN 
    SELECT 
        pa.[FileName],
        fb.ImageURL,
        rd.StoryImage, rd.StoryContent, rd.ALT,
        pr.ReferenceData 
    FROM 
        CS_PostAttachments pa
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        PostFBImageURL fb ON fb.PostID = pa.PostID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        PostRelatedData rd ON rd.PostID = pa.PostID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        PostReferences pr ON pr.PostID = pa.PostID
    WHERE 
        pa.contenttype LIKE 'audio/mpeg' 
        AND pa.FILENAME LIKE '%.mp3' 
        AND pa.isremote = 1 
        AND pa.postid = @Postid ------returns a seperate table
END
```

Comment: I have a question that, if suppose there is need to use either `table variable` or `temp table`,,,which should be used and why?

Comment: In one case it is not working, when there is no data found in `CS_PostAttachments` table all will return `NULL` as where query is dependant on that table

Comment: @PranavBilurkar: yes, obviously - I didn't know which of those four tables is the *driving* table that always has data - you might need to adapt this. I just tried to show what I believe would be the correct and best way to do this

Comment: No, not really - you have to start with one table and then join the others to it ...

Comment: @PranavBilurkar: my response **IS** an example ...... what more can I tell you? You have to pick **one table** as the starting point - where you always have data - and then join in the other tables....

Comment: thanks, i have done that, but i have question for you, shall i ask?

Comment: Is it the best way to return many columns from different table using join or splitting up the columns and returning from other table? Which one of these can hamper on performance and which one does not

Comment: @PranavBilurkar: that's a much too broad question. I recommend using JOINs by default and only resort to something else if you really cannot get the performance to be sufficient

Comment: So, that means when i return many columns using JOIN will not hamper on performance on SP...

Comment: @PranavBilurkar: if you have **proper indexing** in place - no

Comment: Indexing on a column for each table contained in JOIN..right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35218210/converting-rows-to-column-in-sql-server