# Converting rows to column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table `user_travel` with this sample data in it:

[image]

I want a query which returns the output shown below, with the help of the `Visit` column for each `user ID`..

**Expected output**

```
id  FromD-1visit ToD-1visit  FromD-2visit ToD-2visit  FromD-3visit ToD-3visit  UserID
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    2017-05-17  2017-05-17  2016-02-02      NULL      2016-02-01  2016-02-09    2
```

Here `FromD` and `ToD` are `FromDate` and `ToDate` `(columns)`

I've also tried using `PIVOT` but without luck.

Please help..!

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Why "without pivot"?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen Rows does not have redundant data...all have unique

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen still is it possible? if yes, how>?

Comment: @marc_s - any help or suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script does is dynamically.

```
CREATE TABLE #tt(Id INT,FromDate DATETIME,ToDate DATETIME,Visit INT,UserID INT);
INSERT INTO #tt(Id,FromDate,ToDate,Visit,UserID)VALUES
    (1,'20170517','20170517',1,2),
    (6,'20160202',NULL,2,2),
    (7,'20160201','20160209',3,2),
    (8,'20160207','20160201',NULL,3);

-- select distinct Visit ids
SELECT DISTINCT
    Visit
INTO
    #visit_ids
FROM
    #tt
WHERE
    Visit IS NOT NULL;

-- create dynamic select columns (forcing order by Visit id)
DECLARE @sel_cols NVARCHAR(MAX)=STUFF((
    SELECT
        ',[FromD-'+CAST(Visit AS VARCHAR(3))+'visit]=MAX(CASE WHEN Visit='+CAST(Visit AS VARCHAR(3))+' THEN FromDate END)'+
        ',[ToD-'+CAST(Visit AS VARCHAR(3))+'visit]=MAX(CASE WHEN Visit='+CAST(Visit AS VARCHAR(3))+' THEN ToDate END)'
    FROM
        #visit_ids
    ORDER BY
        Visit
    FOR
        XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,''
);

DECLARE @stmt NVARCHAR(MAX)=N'
    SELECT
        id=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY UserId),
        UserId,'+
        @sel_cols+'
    FROM
        #tt
    WHERE
        Visit IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY
        UserId;
';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @stmt;

DROP TABLE #visit_ids;
DROP TABLE #tt;
```

Result:

```
+----+--------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| id | UserId |      FromD-1visit       |       ToD-1visit        |      FromD-2visit       | ToD-2visit |      FromD-3visit       |       ToD-3visit        |
+----+--------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|  1 |      2 | 2017-05-17 00:00:00.000 | 2017-05-17 00:00:00.000 | 2016-02-02 00:00:00.000 | NULL       | 2016-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 2016-02-09 00:00:00.000 |
+----+--------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: What if i need to create a view and return from a above query?

Comment: @PranavBilurkar You cannot do this when using dynamic SQL. You can however determine a maximum number of visits if you know there will never be more than a certain number, then create a static version of the SQL.

Comment: @PranavBilurkar You can see what SQL is being generated by adding a `PRINT @stmt;` or `SELECT @stmt;` to the script. You can then modify this SQL to select for a certain of visits, and use this static SQL as the select statement for your view. GL!

Comment: I did not get you, what you are tryin to say..??

Comment: @PranavBilurkar **1)** You cannot use dynamic SQL in views. **2)** If you want to use a view to display pivotted data, use static SQL.  **3)** To create static SQL for your pivotted data, you can run the script I answered, and include a `PRINT @stmt;` after the `@stmt` was set. **4)** Copy the output of this PRINT statement (see message tab in SSMS) and place it in the definition of the view. **5)** Modify the SQL statement in your view definition to have a certain number of *visit* columns (FromD-1visit, ToD-1visit, ...). Say you expect 10 such columns, copy/paste and change the IDs

Comment: Thanks..Yes, now i've got it, what if i use CTE to create a view??

Comment: @PranavBilurkar You can have a CTE in a view, that's no problem. You will have to rearrange the SELECT statement a bit to select from your CTE instead.

Comment: Create view abc as 
  With
  part 
as
(
SELECT @final=N'
    SELECT distinct 
        id=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY UserId),UserId,'+@xml+'
    FROM User_TravelDetails 
    GROUP BY
        UserId;
';)
select * from part

Comment: @PranavBilurkar I'm sorry Pranav but the comment section is not intended as a question/answer forum. If you have problems formulating your view, start a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/be0db/4)

```
select 
    f1.ID, f1.FromDate as 'FromD-1visit', 
    f1.ToDate as 'ToD-1visit',
    f2.FromDate as 'FromD-2visit', f2.ToDate as 'ToD-2visit',
    f3.FromDate as 'FromD-3visit', f3.ToDate as 'ToD-1visit',
    f1.UserID
from
    user_travel f1
left join  
    user_travel f2 on f2.UserID = f1.UserID and f2.Visit = 2
left join  
    user_travel f3 on f3.UserID = f1.UserID and f3.Visit = 3
where 
    f1.Visit = 1 and f1.UserID = 2
```

Comment: the above query works as expected..but what if there are 12 visits or more than that...because we need to manually add `fromD` and `ToD` for all 12...rather it should be runtime/dynamic, connected to table `Visit`